# Problema con el annotate en django

Tags: python, django, python-3.7, django-admin

He hecho esta función. Y el problema que tengo es que me coge el 1º valor del annotate ("no_modelo=Exists(modelo_faltante)"), pero el 2º ya no me hace caso

```
def check_falta_modelo_vendedor(self, operacion_qs) -> Set[int]:
    vendedor_espanyol = Operacion.objects.filter(pk__in=self.asig_espanya(tt_qs).values_list('agrup_id', flat=True))
    operacion_no_espanyia = tt_qs.exclude(id__in=vendedor_espanyol.values_list('id', flat=True))
    ejec = Ejecutar.objects.non_polymorphic().filter(asig__op_id=OuterRef('pk'))

    modelo_faltante = ejec.filter(Q(modelo=''),
                                  Q(asignacion__vendedor__nombre__isnull=True) | 
                                  Q(asignacion__vendedor__nombre__isnull__alphacode2=Entidad.ALPHACODE_HP))
    modelo_faltante = modelo_faltante.exclude(mercado__pais__alphacode2=Pais.DOMESTIC_ALPHACODE2)
    mala_operac = list()
    for operacion in operacion_no_espanyia.annotate(no_modelo=Exists(modelo_faltante), 


asignacion__vendedor__nombre__isnull__alphacode2=Exists(modelo_faltante)).filter(no_modelos=True, asignacion__vendedor__nombre__isnull__alphacode2=True): # solo coge el 1º en el annotate 
        mala_operac.append(operacion.pk)
        mercado = operacion.mercado.first()
        self.add_error(TREntityException(operacion, f"Falta el modelo del {mercado}", f"Operacion{operacion.pk}", self.module))
    return set(list(super().check_falta_modelo_vendedor(vendedor_espanyol)) + mala_operac)
```

Espero que alguno pueda ayudarme.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Para que tu pregunta llegue a más gente, te recomiendo agregar la etiqueta Python c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he conseguido he tenido que poner lo en distintas variables. En el modelo_faltante dejo el uno o otro. El otro lo pongo en otro requerimiento ("y que cumpla esto")

y luego en el for

```
for operacion in operacion_no_espanyia.annotate(no_modelo=Exists(modelo_faltante), no_vendedor=Exists(missing_vendedor).filter(no_modelo=True, no_vendedor=True):
```